# Manipulation of initial value of recurrence table

Tags: manipulate, recursion

I am studying the behaviour of the recursive function defined by

> $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{1}{x_n}$, $x_0=2$

To get a better understanding of it, I would like to be able to see the "transition" between plots for different values of $x_0$, while I can move $x_0$ freely between some values. My initial idea on how to achieve this, is to use the following code:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[RecurrenceTable[
{a[n + 1] == a[n] - 1/a[n], a[0] == t}, a, {n, 1000}]], {t, -3, 3}]
```

However, this code just makes Mathematica freeze a bit and then display `$Aborted` in the manipulate window, not doing what I want it to do. Why does this not work? How could I approach this problem using different code?

I am using Mathematica 11.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this. The problem is that you initial setting takes toooo long to evaluate.  There is a 5 seconds limit build in.

But may be you should also limit `n` to something lower than `1000` like `25` or so?  (Updated it to use `N@t` in code below, instead of just `t` to make it load faster initially)

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[f[t]],
 {t, -3, 3},
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {t},
 Initialization :> (
   f[t_] := 
    RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] - 1/a[n], a[0] == N@t}, 
     a, {n, 50}]
   )
 ]
```

[image]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So before you had the default `True` and that is why it aborted

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. You make a good point about the evaluation time, when using the integer 2, the eval time increases significantly for larger n. Somewhere between 25 and 30 it becomes uncomfortably large. That's why I put a 2. instead of a 2 in my original plot, which evaluated much, much quicker. Can something similar be done here to decrease the loading time?

Comment: @Tyron yes you can. Just changed the `t` to be numerical. Updated my answer.  So you have to decide if you want `t` to by real or integer. With integer it is much slower to load initially and so you have to use `SynchronousInitialization->False`

Comment: @Nasser: In your answer above, you have a single difference equation: `RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] - 1/a[n], a[0] == N@t},  a, {n, 50}]`. Can you tell me how your `code` needs to be changed if you have, say, 10 recurrence equations. How would you replicate your `code` for this extended problem? Thanks.
`

Answer (score 3):

Somehow the recursion poses a problem, but the iterative counterpart is rather straightforward. You can do

```
f[u_] := u - 1/u;
Manipulate[
 a = {N@t};
 Do[AppendTo[a, f[Last[a]]], 1000];
 ListPlot[a, PlotRange -> {-50, 50}],
 {t, -3, 3}]
```

[image]